# start and end date validation in HTML5

Tags: html

I am new to HTML5. I want to select start and end dates in my textbox which is input type date. start date must disable future dates and end date should enable greater than start date.

Comment: What have you already tried? It's worth pointing out that the `type="date"` input attribute isn't widely supported at all (it doesn't work on IE, Firefox or Safari and only partially works on Chrome and Opera): http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime, so you'd be better off using some JavaScript to get this to work.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use JQuery for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can set value of the start date to min attribute of the end date.

```
start.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (start.value) end.min = start.value;
}, false);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/int32_t/5zLeK/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Parsley JS plugin for this. I've used it in several projects and it's great for setting up quick & precise validation.

[Parsley JS](http://parsleyjs.org/)

Comment: I'd advise against using this plugin unless you're planning on invalidating your HTML with non-attributes like "parsley-trigger".

Comment: To be honest I've mainly used it in offline/software instances where there wasn't a great need for perfect validation

Comment: Specification conformance should be mandatory regardless of what you're working on. The author of this plugin should have known better than to ignore the `data-*` attributes which are defined specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Update - The plugin uses the data-* attributes these days.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using JQuery for date validation. JQuery is a JavaScript library, here is a good date range picker for you to get started.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: Having to implement both jQuery and jQuery UI to get a simple date picker up and running is really overkill. `Date()` is a built-in JavaScript object and doesn't require jQuery for validation.